# Cropping area from project to layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, layouts

Using QGIS, I need to "crop" some area from the map to layout and export it to pdf like in the picture below.

Can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how the [print payout](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html?highlight=layout) works?

Comment: no, i have a map and i want to take only part of it and export to layout like in the photo,that take only part of hte river and not all of the area

Comment: So, just zoom in to that area in the print layout?

Comment: no sorry it dosent work i need some tool to choose the path of the river,it is too long for just do a zoom

Comment: Then turn off the other layers?

Comment: Think about it like that, I have a map of all over Europe and I would like to crop from here the path of some river how start from germany and end in poland, so how can I do it? I cant do zoom it will not help me

Comment: I guess you need to provide example data and an example of your desired output.